# I am facing problem while running my express app with docker

Tags: javascript, docker, express, docker-image

I am running my express app in VM using docker image.... the image is working fine but I am unable to stop the express app
^c isn't working either
following is my Dockerfile

```
FROM  node

RUN mkdir -p /home/app

COPY ./my_express_app /home/app


CMD ["node", "/home/app/index.js"]`
```

this is my code

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.get('/', (req,res)=>{
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "index.html"));
})

app.listen(5000, () => console.log("server running at port 5000!!"));
```

Comment: There isn't much detail here. What does the .Dockerfile look like?

Comment: ^C is being sent to the stdin to whatever process is currently running in your terminal. If that process is NodeJS, it will stop. If there is no process running, the terminal will ignore it. To stop containers, use `docker stop [id]`. Whatsoever, it is unclear which steps were taken to start the container, so we can't really help with stopping it.